# Technicalities regarding the definition of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I encountered an interesting claim in a model solution for Rudin's exercise 24 in chapter 2. Claim of the exercise is that: "Any metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit is also separable". The aforementioned model solution begins as:

> Fix $\delta > 0$. Since $X \neq \varnothing$, we can pick $x_1 \in X$. Then we can choose $x_2 \in X$ such that $d(x_1, x_2) \geq \delta$. Otherwise we can replace $\delta$ by $\frac{\delta}{2}$ and choose $x_2 \in X$ such that $d(x_1, x_2) \geq \frac{\delta}{2}$. Otherwise the process of halving the radius $\delta$ must stop after a finite number of steps because $X \subset \mathcal{B}\left(x_1, \frac{\delta}{2^n}\right)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies that $X = \varnothing$, a contradiction.

Why exactly does "$X \subset \mathcal{B}\left(x_1, \frac{\delta}{2^n}\right)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$" imply that "$X = \varnothing$"? For example if $X = \{x_1\}$, then $d(x_1, x) = 0 \forall x \in X$. Rudin himself does not seem to exclude the possibility that the set in the tuple of a metric space $(M, d)$ is empty (i.e. $M = \varnothing$). Therefore i.) is it universally accepted that a metric space is empty, ii.) why can't the singleton set $\{x_1\}$ constitute a metric space in this particular case (I understand that such a space wouldn't be a meaningful one, but I don't see how it violates anything).

Comment: The 'model solution' is wrong. We get $X=\{x\}$, not $X=\emptyset$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How would you argue about finding inductively the second element $x_2$ so that $d(x_1, x_2) \geq \delta/2^n$ for some positive integer $n$?

Comment: What's the linit of a set?

Comment: @EpsilonAway exactly as in the book, $X=\{x\}$ is still a contradiction since you are assuming $X$ to be infinite

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti But are we assuming $X$ to be infinite? The only assumption is that: "every infinite set in $X$ has a limit point". If there are not infinite sets in $X$, then isn't the property vacuously true?

Comment: If there are no infinite sets in $X$ then $X$ is finite, and finite spaces are separable since the whole space is a countable dense subset